# verify that string matches a regex pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is there a way to verify with Regex that a string matches a patter like so:

- 1.001
- 1.002
- 15.001

Where the pattern is:

- any number followed by
- dot character
- followed by three (3) numbers

Given that patters things like this would fail:

- A.001
- 1.0001
- 1,001
  ...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
^\d+\.\d{3}$
```